# jQuery full calendar plugin Time Zone problem

Tags: jquery, time, timezone, fullcalendar

I'm using full calendar scheduler view to display room bookings.
Everything is working fine except the TimeZone.

I have created a event with following Date and Time:

**Start Date:** 2018-11-21 19:00:00.000
**End Date:** 2018-11-21 20:00:00.000

But, in calendar the event is showing with different time. It is showing 5:30am to 6:30am

How to set it to Indian Timezone or user timezone?

Here is my code:

```
function LoadBookings() {

    var rooms = [];
    var events = [];

    var s = $("#hdnStudio").val();
    var u = $("#hdnUnit").val();
    var f = $("#hdnFloor").val();
    var r = $("#hdnRoom").val();

    if ($('#calendar').length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/RoomBooking/Events',
            data: { studio: s, unit: u, floor: f },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (result) {
            if (result != null) {

                // Get all Events
                $.each(result.events, function (i, v) {
                    if (v.IsAllDayEvent) {
                        events.push({
                            id: v.Id,
                            resourceId: v.RoomId,
                            start: moment(v.StartDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                            end: moment(v.EndDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                            title: v.Title
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        events.push({
                            id: v.Id, resourceId: v.RoomId,
                            start: moment(v.StartDate).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"),
                            end: moment(v.EndDate).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"),
                            title: v.Title
                        });
                    }
                });

                // Get all Rooms
                $.each(result.rooms, function (i, v) {
                    rooms.push({
                        id: v.Id,
                        title: v.Name,
                        eventColor: v.EventColor
                    });
                });

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    schedulerLicenseKey: "GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source",
                    editable: false, // enable draggable events
                    aspectRatio: 1.8,
                    resourceAreaWidth: '15%',
                    slotEventOverlap: false,
                    minTime: "09:00:00",
                    maxTime: "23:00:00",
                    scrollTime: '09:30', // undo default 6am scrollTime
                    header: {
                        left: 'today prev,next',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'timelineDay,agendaWeek,month,listWeek'
                    },
                    defaultView: 'timelineDay',
                    resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
                    height: 500,
                    resources: rooms,
                    events: events,
                    timezone: 'UTC',
                    dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view, resourceObj) {
                        var selectedDate = moment(date);
                        if (moment().diff(selectedDate) <= 0) {
                            var url = "/RoomBooking/Create?roomId=" + resourceObj.id + "&sDate=" + date.format();
                            $("#room-booking-modal .modal-content").load(url, function () {
                                $("#room-booking-modal").modal({ show: true });
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                        var url = "/RoomBooking/Edit?id=" + calEvent.id;
                        $("#room-booking-modal .modal-content").load(url, function () {
                            $("#room-booking-modal").modal({ show: true });
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set timezone property in fullcalendar "local" it will render the client’s timezone.

Use this mode if you store timezone information for your events and you want events displayed differently depending on the local timezone of each end-user’s computer.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
    },
    timezone:'local', // you can set a time zone 'local'
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json',
    loading: function(bool) {
      $('#loading').toggle(bool);
    },
    eventRender: function(event, el) {
      // render the timezone offset below the event title
      if (event.start.hasZone()) {
        el.find('.fc-title').after(
          $('<div class="tzo"/>').text(event.start.format('Z'))
        );
      }
    }
  });
```

Please take a look in [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone).

Here is a [live](https://codepen.io/negirox/pen/XyZmWx?&editors=001) example.

Comment: In DB, it is stored as `2018-11-21 19:00:00.000` but, while displaying it is `2018-11-22 05:30:00.000`. It is displaying in 22nd day slot instead of 21st day slot

Comment: are you still facing same problem after using local ?

Comment: Yes, same issue. I'm getting TimeZone info in cell. But events are displaying in wrong slots. As I said,  It is displaying in 22nd day slot instead of 21st day slot

Comment: i think you don't need a moment("your date"); just use without it

Comment: Without moment also same issue. will JSON conversion changes the timezone by default?

Comment: firstly you need to check what is v.StartDate and v.EndDate is returning. without conversion. just print your returned object and check value.

Comment: v.StartDate and v.EndDate is returning original dates only, but while rendering dates are converting into different timezone

Comment: then check with this moment(v.EndDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"), what is it returning

Comment: I solved the problem. Converted the value from DateTime to String. Now, Json will treat it as regular string instead of DateTime (no need of parsing with timezone).